# Topology on the Set of Prime Ideals Which is Not the Zariski Topology

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, category-theory, functors

An exercise in Hilton/Stammbach's *A Course in Homological Algebra* reads: "Let $\Phi$ associate with each commutative unitary ring $R$ the set of its prime ideals. Show that $\Phi$ is a contravariant functor from the category of commutative unitary rings to the category of sets. Assign to the set of prime ideals of $R$ the topology in which a base of neighborhoods is given by the sets of prime ideals containing a given ideal $J$, as $J$ runs through the ideals of $R$. Show that $\Phi$ is then a contravariant functor to the category of topological spaces."

Having studied prime spectra a little bit, I thought I knew where this exercise was going, but the topology the authors describe is different from the Zariski topology, where the sets $V(J)$ for $J$ an ideal of $R$ form the *closed* sets, not a basis of open sets. Is this a mistake in the book, or is what they describe another useful topology to put on the set of prime ideals of $R$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sets $V(I) = \{\mathfrak{p} : I \subseteq \mathfrak{p}\}$ are usually not closed under unions (thus are not the open sets of a topology), but the exercise just states that this is a base of a topology, which is certainly true. Of course, this is not the Zariski topology, since in that topology the sets $V(I)$ are usually not open. For any ring homomorphism $\varphi : R \to S$ the induced map $\mathrm{Spec}(\varphi) : \mathrm{Spec}(S) \to \mathrm{Spec}(R)$ satisfies $\mathrm{Spec}(\varphi)^{-1}(V(I)) = V(\varphi(I) \cdot S)$, showing that it is also continuous with respect to this alternative topology.

By the way, one can put this topology in the context of Yves Diers' theory in [Une construction universelle des spectres topologies spectrales et faisceaux structuraux](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00927878408823101). (For a more recent account, see Osmond's papers [On Diers's theory I](https://export.arxiv.org/abs/2012.00853) and [II](http://arxiv-export-lb.library.cornell.edu/abs/2012.02167).) This paper shows that a functor $U : \mathcal{A} \to \mathcal{B}$ satisfying certain conditions gives rise to a spectrum construction: Every object $B \in \mathcal{B}$ yields a topological space $\mathrm{Spec}_U(B)$ together with a $\mathcal{B}$-valued sheaf whose stalks have distinguished $U$-preimages. The classical case is the inclusion $\mathbf{LCRing} \hookrightarrow \mathbf{CRing}$ from the category of local commutative rings into the category commutative rings, which gives the locally ringed space $\mathrm{Spec}(B)$ of a commutative ring $B$. But the inclusion functor $\mathbf{Int} \hookrightarrow \mathbf{CRing}$ from integral domains and injective ring maps also satisfies the assumption. The spectrum of $B \in \mathbf{CRing}$ here is the set of prime ideals of $B$, but equipped with the topology whose basis are the sets $V(I)$, the structure sheaf is the sheaf associated to $V(I) \mapsto B/\sqrt{I}$, and its stalk at $\mathfrak{p}$ is the integral domain $B/\mathfrak{p}$.